# Change speed of audio by transforming samples NOT the sound card speed (in Java)

Tags: java, android, audio

I have an application that "syncs" multiple devices playing the same sound in Java.  In order to do this I need to slightly speed up/slow down the sound playback.

I originally tried this by changing my audio card's sample rate (via Android's AudioTrack api or the Java sound api for the desktop).  Unfortunately changing the sample rate on some sound cards introduces a lag and a "popping" noise.

So is there a way to remove/add samples to my bytestream of audio data without making the audio sound "weird"?  Perhaps a library can do this?

Comment: Have you even tried to google for a Java resampling library?

Comment: Ah "resampling" is the term I am looking for.  Thanks!